# Image captured from camera not displaying in imageview android

Tags: android, camera

I have a problem, that when i have taken an image from camera, image not displaying in imageview.

I created the code by referring the following link

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

I am posting my code, please have a look,

```
public  void takeImage(View v) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "sample_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();

    galleryAddPic();

    return image;
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The image captured is storing in SDcard. But not showing in imageview.

Where i have gone wrong. I have tried a lot. But no result. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: instead of use this library its hard for first time but easy to use every time https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library

Comment: are you providing the right path of image in sd-card to the image view? are you getting some values in your imagebitmap or not? here- `Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");`

Comment: @sud : It always displays `Something went wrong` message. Not even going to try block.

Comment: replace your toast with- `Toast.makeText(this, e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` it will show what exactly the error is

Comment: show what error it will show then?

Comment: @sud : now no error is display.

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @sud : now it's showing `java.lang.nullpointerexception`

Comment: yes that means your **imageBitmap** variable in `Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");` is null may be... apply debugger to find on which line it is showing null value..

Comment: @sud : How to solve this in my coding.

Comment: you have to modify your url..also check whether your variable `data` is empty or what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the temp file, just put the Uri in the intent. After the capture, check the file existence of that Uri. If it exists, capture has been done successfully.